# Fake directory containing png informations

Tags: c, unix, directory

As we all know we can have `/dev/video0` as a directory for receiving the output of a webcam.

Is it possible to create a fake `/dev/something` directory through a `C` program and continuously output there the contents of some created png files in order to create a `fake webcam` for example?

I will then read the `live` stream for an other application.

Thanks.

Comment: It depends; it's not as simple as dumping decoded pngs into a file.
If you want it to act as a fake webcam you will probably end up writing a device driver, to answer to ioctls and whatnot. On the bright side, you won't have to deal with actual hardware so it will be much simpler than a regular device driver.

Comment: If I would like just to dump everything in a file and then read everything or just `cat ` the contents? Is that possible?

Comment: If your 'other application' is dumb enough that it just reads frame data, maybe. If it tries to configure/start a real webcam before reading, don't think so. Also, the stream from a webcam will probably be raw YUV or at best something precompressed with some movie related codec, not png. I haven't touched video4linux in a looong time, so I'm afraid I can't be more specific than that. Hopefully someone with recent experience will come along and explain better.

Comment: Just to get the details straight: `/dev/video0` is not a directory, it is a device node. This is a special entity in the file system that is expected to handle the specific operations that @Torp mentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is a place in the filesystem where some application can read some specific data, use `mkfifo` to create it.

Then you can write a producer that writes whatever you need at whatever bitrate to it and have a consumer reading from it. If you output what the consumer expects, you might be able to get something that resembles a "live stream" of faked data.